# java.lang.SecurityException in Struts2 with display tag

Tags: java, struts2, displaytag

HelloWorld is my ActionSupport class and the pop method is loading the values to countryList object of Country class type.

```
package example;    
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HelloWorld extends ActionSupport {

    ArrayList<Country> countryList = new ArrayList<Country>();

    public ArrayList<Country> getCountryList() {
        return countryList;
    }

    public void setCountryList(ArrayList<Country> countryList) {
        this.countryList = countryList;
    }

    public String pop() {
        countryList.add(new Country("IND", "INDIA"));
        countryList.add(new Country("PAK", "PAKISTAN"));

        System.out.println("countryList " + countryList);

        return SUCCESS;
    }

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {

        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

The **struts.xml** is

```
<struts>
    <package name="example" namespace="/example" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="HelloWorld" method="pop" class="example.HelloWorld">
            <result name="success">/example/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

and **jsp page** is:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://displaytag.sf.net" prefix="display" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
        HAI

        <display:table name="${countryList}"  class="Country" uid="row" pagesize="20" sort="list" requestURI="/example/HelloWorld" >
            <display:column property="id" title="ID" />
            <display:column property="name" />
        </display:table>
    </body>
</html>
```

When i run this application,it shows the following error :

**description**
 The server encountered an internal error () that prevented
 it from fulfilling this request.

**exception**
     javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.SecurityException: class  "org.apache.commons.collections.FastHashMap"'s signer information does
 not match signer information of other classes in the same package

**root cause**
     java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.apache.commons.collections.FastHashMap"'s signer information does
 not match signer information of other classes in the same packa

Please solve this.

Comment: can you just try with simple iterator tag of struts2 to check if this is being caused by display tag?

Answer (score 2):

As per few forums there could be a jar conflict here. Please verify all the included jars to see if there is duplication of class `org.apache.commons.collections.FastHashMap` in them. Remove the duplicated and jar and that should resolve this issue.